# What is the optimal schema for a scalable app using mongodb as a database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I am building a new app that requires a user ,that have many farms and 
that farm haves many devices and that device have many parameter.
A user should be able to see all the devices in A Farm and on click of a device should list all the parameters.

I have used mongodb as a database and I am using mongoose to create user through an api in express framework.My current approach i to create a user first and then edit the farm field but i am unable to do that .

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Device Schema
const Device = new Schema({

  modelNumber: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  deviceType: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description:{
      type:String,
      required:false   
  },

  deviceLocation:[ 
    {
      latitude:Number,
      longitude:Number
    }
  ],

  AddedDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },

});

// User Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  location:{
      type:String,
      required:true
  },
  createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  farm:[
      {
        _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        description:String,
        farmAddDate:{type:Date,default:Date.now},
        device:[{
                Device
        }]
     }
 ]   

});


module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

I expect the api should be able to save farm data.

Comment: Please provide the code for whatever you are doing to update the data

Comment: I think I would define a different schema for farm where farm.user would be a user ObjectId and I'd include a field farm in device that would be a farm ObjectId.

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya i am using api .Shall i share it?

Comment: @VirgilioGM I am defining farm in User,Shall i do differently,Please share what i need to do!!